# OptionsMenu - How to change options menu background layout

Tags: android, optionmenu

I want to change the background layout of the `OptionsMenu`. Not from `styles.xml` but dynamically on java. I want to get the inflate view and change it. I have not found such method that solves my problem. I want something like

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    // Layout root = menu.getView();
}
```

I'm using this options menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/options_menu_more"
        android:title=""
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_vert"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/options_menu_1"
                android:title=""
                android:orderInCategory="1" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/options_menu_2"
                android:title=""
                android:orderInCategory="2" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/options_menu_3"
                android:title=""
                android:orderInCategory="3" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/options_menu_4"
                android:title=""
                android:orderInCategory="4" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but you need to create a new layer for your menu. then with layoutInflater to get custom layer. and findViews. Such as `root.findViewById(anyView) `

Comment: Can you provide some code?